# How to rename variables (bs.as style) when using reason-apollo?

Tags: graphql, apollo, reason

I'm running a `reason-apollo` query on a schema that uses the variable `end`, which is reserved in ReasonML. I've set up the type like so:

```ml
type endContainer {
  [bs.as "end"]
  end_
};
```

But not sure what to put in my graphql query:

```ml
endContainer @bsRecord {
  end_ // Doesn't work ("unknown field")
  end  // Doesn't work either ("the record field end cannot be found")
}
```

Is the `bs.as` modifier perhaps only usable in JS interop but not picked up by apollo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an alias for `end`:

```ml
endContainer @bsRecord {
  end_: end
}
```